# Python pandas conditional ffill. Fill the month beginning value till that month's end

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The code below produces sample dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(35), freq='D')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': days, 'col2': data})
df = df.set_index('test')
```

The value on 1st of December is as follows

```
df.loc['2021-12-01 22:59:41.332749']
```

Which outputs `9`
My question is how to use "ffill" method to have this value 9 for all days of December?
I want the month beginning value to be filled till end of that month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace values for all days except the first day of the month with NaNs and use `.ffill()`

```
df.loc[df.index.day != 1, 'col2'] = np.nan
df['col2'] = df['col2'].ffill()
```